# Splitting a string by white space and a period when not surrounded by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that similar questions have been asked many times, but my regular expression knowledge is pretty bad and I can't get it to work for my case.
So here is what I am trying to do:

I have a text and I want to separate the sentences. Each sentence ends with some white space and a period (there can be one or many spaces before the period, but there is always at least one).

At the beginning I used `/\s+\./` and it worked great for separating the sentences, but then I noticed that there are cases such as this one: 
 "some text . some text".

Now, I don't want to separate the text in quotes. I searched and found a lot of solutions that work great for spaces (for example: `/(".*?"|[^"\s]+)+(?=\s*|\s*$)/)`, but I was not able to modify them to separate by white space and a period.

Here is the code that I am using at the moment.

```
var regex = /\s+\./;
        var result = regex.exec(fullText);
        if(result == null) {
            break;
        }
        var length = result[0].length;
        var startingPoint = result.index;
        var currentSentence = fullText.substring(0,startingPoint).trim();

        fullText = fullText.substring(startingPoint+length);
```

I am separating the sentences one by one and removing them from the full text.
The `length` var represents the size of the portion that needs to be removed and `startingPoint` is the position on which the portion starts. The code is part of a larger `while` cycle.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code that you have currently tried?

Comment: You cannot `split()` if you need to skip some parts of the sentences, you can only *match* them.

Comment: Try  `\s*((?:"[^"]*"|(?:(?!\s+\.|"[^"]*").)+)+)\s+\.`

Comment: I updated my post to show the code that I am using.

Comment: Your code does not work at all, please check.

Comment: Well that's weird because it works fine here. I guess there might be some browser compatibility problems ? Anyway, I will change the code to work with match if there is a way to make it work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting you may try and match all sentences between delimiters. In this case it will be easier to skip delimiters in quotes. The respective regex is:

```
(.*?(?:".*?".*?)?|.*?)(?: \.|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iS9fN6/1

The sentences then may be retrieved in this loop:

```
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match[1]); // each next sentence is in match[1]
}
```

BUT! This particular expression makes `regex.exec(input)` return true infinitely! (Looks like a candidate to one more SO question.)

So I can only suggest a workaround with removing the `$` from the expression. This will cause the regex to miss the last part which later may be extracted as a trailer not matched by the regex:

```js
var input = "some text . some text . \"some text . some text\" some text . some text";
//var regex = /(.*?(?:".*?".*?)?|.*?)(?: \.|$)/g;
var regex = /(.*?(?:".*?".*?)?|.*?) \./g;
var trailerPos = 0;
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match[1]);    // each next sentence is in match[1]
    trailerPos = match.index + match[0].length;
}
if (trailerPos < input.length) {
    console.log(input.substring(trailerPos));    // the last sentence in
                                                 // input.substring(trailerPos)
}
```

**Update:**

If sentences span multiple lines, the regex won't work since `.` pattern does not match the newline character. In this case just use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`:

```js
var input = "some \ntext . some text . \"some\n text . some text\" some text . so\nm\ne text";
var regex = /([\s\S]*?(?:"[\s\S]*?"[\s\S]*?)?|[\s\S]*?) \./g;
var trailerPos = 0;
var sentences = []
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    sentences.push(match[1]);
    trailerPos = match.index + match[0].length;
}
if (trailerPos < input.length) {
    sentences.push(input.substring(trailerPos)); 
}
sentences.forEach(function(s) {
    console.log("Sentence: -->%s<--", s);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem I encountered is when the sentence is on multiple lines (separated with new line). For example:
some text in the first line \n
some more in the second line \n
text in the third line . \n
The code only gets the last line in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the encode and decode of javascript while sending and receiving.